# Compute Limit of p-adic Cauchy Sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, cauchy-sequences

This has really been irking at me and I really should be able to do this but for some reason I can't so I'll ask on here. It is easy to compute the rational "equivalent" of a Cauchy sequence of the form
\[ p^{0k} + p^{1k} + p^{2k} + p^{3k} + \cdots \]
in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by scaling each term by $p - 1$ and adding on the sequences produced by multiplying by $p, p^2, \dots, p^{k - 1}$ to get some nice form for $-1$. However, no matter how hard I try, I can't seem to find an analogue for this if we release the restriction of $p$ prime (e.g. $1 + 6^2 + 6^4 + \cdots$) and change the field to be $\mathbb{Q}_{p'}$ where $p'$ is not necessarily related to $p$. So basically, how does one compute a the limit of
\[ 1 + 6^2 + 6^4 + \cdots \]
in, say, the field $\mathbb{Q}_2$?

Comment: Rewrite each partial some as a (finite length) $p'$-adic expansion.

Comment: but $6^k$ doesn't exactly expand too well in terms of powers of $2$

Comment: true. Not much you can do about that though. It will converge, however. Also, the limit might not be in $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1+\sum_{n=1} p^{nk}=1+\sum_{n=1} (p^k)^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^m (p^k)^{n}=\frac{p^{k(m+1)}-1}{p^k-1}$$
in your example you have $p=6$ and $k=2$ so we have
$$\frac{36^{(m+1)}-1}{35}$$

So what number can be subtract from this such that it gives a power of two number? $-\frac{1}{35}$ works as we get

$$\frac{36^{(m+1)}-1}{35}+\frac{1}{35}=\frac{36^{(m+1)}}{35}=\frac{2^{2(m+1)}3^{2(m+1)}}{35}$$
at which we get for $\mathbb{Q}_2$
$$|\sum_{n=0}^m (6^2)^{n}+\frac{1}{35}|=2^{-2(m+1)}$$
which we can do normal cauchy etc and get it converges to $-\frac{1}{35}$